# Statements on reasons to vote against US H. R. 6930, a bill to confiscate assets from sanctioned Russian oligarchs & use the funds to support Ukraine

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, ukraine, sanctions, specific-legislation

What are the reasons that 8 US Representatives holding *very* different political views voted against US H. R. 6930, a bill to confiscate assets from sanctioned Russian oligarchs and use the funds to support Ukraine?

I am looking for official statements or fact-based analysis, **no** opinions or speculations.

[image: NO votes on US H. R. 6930]

**SEE ALSO:**

- H.R.6930 - Asset Seizure for Ukraine Reconstruction Act: https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/6930
- Roll Call 130 | Bill Number: H. R. 6930: https://clerk.house.gov/Votes/2022130

Note: The sources below do not appear to be neutral, but I could not quickly find more neutral references:

- Four Republicans, four Democrats vote ‘no’ on bill urging Biden to confiscate assets from sanctioned oligarchs: https://thehill.com/news/house/3469582-four-republicans-four-democrats-vote-no-on-bill-urging-biden-to-confiscate-assets-from-sanctioned-oligarchs/
- Inside the Squad’s ‘Putin problem’: https://nypost.com/2022/03/25/inside-the-squads-putin-problem/
- Democratic socialist group linked to AOC claims US ‘set the stage’ for Russian invasion of Ukraine: https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/democratic-socialist-group-linked-aoc-213816266.html

Comment: Official statements are one ting, but you can't really do solely "fact-based analysis" when it comes to political motivations.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Congressional Record from April 27th](https://www.congress.gov/117/crec/2022/04/27/168/69/CREC-2022-04-27-house.pdf) doesn't hold any explanation from any of the representatives who voted against the bill, although it does note that Rep. Madison Cawthorn changed his vote from Yea to Nay.

Rep. Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez's staff, however, have released [a statement](https://twitter.com/RepAOC/status/1519687572905152512) on Twitter explaining her decision to vote in opposition - presumably other members of 'the Squad' who voted in opposition; Reps. Omar, Tlaib & Bush had similar reasons:-

> Oligarchs should suffer huge financial losses, which is why the Congresswoman participated in designing and voted for the toughest sanctions in recent memory. But this vote asked President Biden to violate the 4th Amendment, seize private property, and determine where it would go - all without due process. This sets a risky new precedent in the event of future Presidents who may seek to abuse that expansion of power, especially with so many of our communities already fighting civil asset forfeiture.

Rep. Chip Roy has also released [a statement on his website](https://roy.house.gov/media/press-releases/rep-roys-statement-hr-6930) regarding his vote:-

> This bill wasn’t just about taking Russian assets to support Ukraine,   which I support generally; instead, as usual, this Congress is blindly giving power to the executive branch to fund poorly-defined 'democracy and human rights programming and monitoring.' I will not support that, especially when this administration views such things as pro-life policies, traditional views on marriage, and elementary understandings of human biology as potential threats to human rights.

Comment: So Chip Roy thinks that "Humanitarian and development assistance for the Russian people, including democracy and human rights programming and monitoring." means we're authorizing POTUS to use these funds to promote gay marriage, abortion, and LGBTQ right in Russia? And he voted against it because of that one clause.